# How to use dynamic table name for sub query where the dynamic value coming from its own main query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have formed this query to get the desired output mentioned below:

```
select tbl.id, tbl.label, tbl.input_type, tbl.table_name
case when tbl.input_type = 'dropdown' or tbl.input_type = 'searchable-dropdown'
then  (select json_agg(opt) from tbl.table_name) as opt) end as options
from mst_config as tbl;
```

I want output like below:

```
id  |                      label                         |     input_type      |    table_name           |                          options                          
----+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------- 
  1 | Gender                                             | dropdown            | mst_gender              | [{"id":1,"label":"MALE"},
    |                                                    |                     |                         |  {"id":2,"label":"FEMALE"}]
 
 2  | SS                                                 | dropdown            | mst_ss                  | [{"id":1,"label":"something"},
    |                                                    |                     |                         |  {"id":2,"label_en":"something"}]
```

But, I'm facing a problem while using,

```
select json_agg(opt) from tbl.table_name) as opt
```

In the above part "tbl.table_name", I wanted to use it as dynamic table name but it's not working.

Then, I have searched a lot and found something like `Execute format('select * from %s', table_name)`, where tablename is the dynamic table name. I have even tried the same with  postgres function.

But I faced an issue again while using the format method. The reason is I want to use the variable for which the value needs to come from its own main query value instead of already having it in a variable. so this one was also not working.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out on this. Also if there are any other possibilities available to achieve this output, help me on that as well.

Comment: Is it only those two tables `mst_gender` and `mst_ss`, or could it be really arbitrary tables that your data might reference?

Comment: There are almost more than 15 tables, in future it may even increase. So only I thought of adding the table name in a separate column and tried to achieve it this way.

Comment: Why do you have 15 different tables with an `opt` column that all mean the same? Move all values into a single table, and give them a "table_name" identifier by which you can filter.

Comment: Actually, those are all master tables containing constant values that are shown in dropdown fields, so we can't club into single table.

Comment: Yes you can. It should be a single table `dropdown_values`, with columns like `dropdown_id`, `option_value` and `option_label`.

Comment: But those are all of different types. And I cannot change it since it is already used in production

Comment: What do you mean by "different types"? Surely they have the same column types, as otherwise your dynamic query wouldn't work either.

Comment: same columns only, but since it is currently running db in production, we are not allowed to change it

Comment: Sure you can migrate also production databases - talk to the database admins. And even if that is not easily done, you can build a view that consists of a union of these tables, each with an identifier.

Comment: Okay, let me check. Thanks